# $H(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x) + tg(x)|^p\,dx$ differentiable or not?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $p > 1$ and $f$, $g \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. Define$$H(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x) + tg(x)|^p\,dx$$for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I have two questions.

1. Is $H$ a differentiable or not?
2. If so, what is its derivative?

Answer (score 1):

For any $h\in\mathbb{R}$ 
$$
\frac{H(t+h)-H(t)}{h}=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{|f(x)+t\,g(x)+h\,g(x)|^p-|f(x)+t\,g(x)|^p}{h}\,dx.
$$
The integrand converges pointwise to $p(g(x)+t\,g(x))|f(x)+t\,g(x)|^{p-2}$. Moreover, it is bounded by
$$
|h|\,|g|\,\max(|f|,t\,|g|)^{p-1}.
$$
Now use the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Hi. Why is $|h|\,|g|\,\max(|f|,t\,|g|)^{p-1} \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$? The product of two integrable functions need not be integrable.